# owl.carousel responsive error in mobile view after hard refreshing site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a site which is (http://www.echo-group.com.au/), in home page right after slider there is Carousel of three inf boxes and in mobile view (developer mode) after hard refresh or viewing link in actual mobile device it shows disturbed view it suppose to show one column instead of 3 at once.

I tried to update owl.carousel JS and CSS files but error is still there i am stuck here need guidance kindly help me out it will be a big help thanks!!!

Kindly see these screenshot for further understanding the Error

1. [ErrorScreenshot](http://prntscr.com/nrp0n4)
2. [how its need to be](http://prntscr.com/nrp11u)

Comment: I don't know what going on in chrome (firefox working good), but you can try to add $('.services_carousel').owlCarousel().trigger('refresh.owl.carousel'); after init

Comment: still same after that update, but yes it's working perfectly fine in firefox and in chrome and safari its messed up

Comment: Just try to remove revolution slider section and check. It seems that you have a conflict between revolution slider and next owl carousel. Just give a try to remove rev slider .

Comment: sure trying now, thanks for help

Comment: @MominIqbal bro your solution is worked thanks but I need slider too, is there a way to have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `theme.js` file, in FUNCTION CALLING section, use `revolutionSliderActiver()` above `services_carousel()`. Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nrskqu kindly see attached file I have done as you said but it's still same.

Comment: This need to be changed in in below call back function and not the function body.